# Performing arithmetic on string values

Tags: string, types, lua, int

I would like to ask something about data types in Lua.
I get from serial link some message (command:value) like this:

```
tmp_string = "BRAKE:1"
```

then I parse this string to command and value in two different functions (one is for command and other one is for value). This is function for parsing value

```
function parser(value)
    index = string.find(value, ":")
    result = value.sub(value, index+1)
    return result
end
```

I would like to now what sort of data type result is? If I use string match it works.

```
...if string.match(state, "1") then...
```

However it also works when I do something like this

```
x = (state*65536)/3.2808)
```

I thought the result is string, but I don't understand why it works also with numerical operations. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you tell Lua to treat a string as a number, and it can, it will convert it.

Comment: `string.match(state, "1")` means "does the number after conversion to a string has symbol '1' somewhere inside?"

Answer (score 4):

### Lua 5.3 Reference Manual, §3.4.1 - [`Arithmetic Operators`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1)

> With the exception of exponentiation and float division, the arithmetic operators work as follows: If both operands are integers, the operation is performed over integers and the result is an integer. Otherwise, **if both operands are numbers or strings that can be converted to numbers** (see §3.4.3), **then they are converted to floats**, the operation is performed following the usual rules for floating-point arithmetic (usually the IEEE 754 standard), and the result is a float.

*Emphasis is mine.*

When dealing with operations, Lua will attempt to convert string operands to floats, and if it works - it works. If it fails, you get an error.

```
>| '55' / 2
<| 27.5

>| 'foo' / 2
<| error: [string "return 'foo' / 2"]:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value
```

If you want to be explicit about this (and safe) use [`tonumber`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-tonumber), and handle the `nil`-case.

If you need to know the type of a value in Lua, you can pass the variable to [`type`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-type) and check the resulting string.